# Get Cloudkit to send notifications to your app everytime something shows up in the Default Zone

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I am making a chat app through CloudKit. Every time someone sends a message that message shows up in the default zone in CloudKit. So I want everyone else to receive a local notification when something gets added to the default zone. Here is a image showing my CloudKit database:

[image: CloudKit Database]

Does anyone know how I can do this? Also there are multiple chat rooms so I don't want notifications from one room going to another room. I don't know how complicated this will get but it is very important for what I am doing. Even if you are not totally sure about the answer please say what you think it would help a lot.

Comment: Have you read through the [CloudKit Quick Start](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987)? It talks about how to do this.

Comment: @rmaddy I have read through lots of this but it doesn't show exactly how to do it the way I want to. For instance how do I keep the notifications out of multiple chatrooms when I only want it for one?

Comment: You need a field in the record indicating the chat room and each user needs to subscribe to the appropriate chatroom using the proper predicate on the subscription. Go through the quick start and look at the section about subscriptions.

Comment: I will read this but do you have any code I can please use?

Comment: You need to try some stuff. When you have attempted something and you get stuck, update your question with a concrete issue. We aren't here to do your work for you. We are here to help you move forward with a specific issue.

Comment: But this article is in Objective C not Swift...